# Spark sql DataFrame class does not exist

Tags: java, maven, apache-spark, dataframe

I have added maven dependency for using DataFrame in my java spark application. As I know the dependency should be stated in pom.xml according to the following format:

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
<artifactId>spark-sql_2.10</artifactId>
<version>1.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

But when I want to import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame to my code, DataFrame class is unknown! Any idea why this happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> i think your version is wrong. Add these codes to your pom.xml

```
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-core_2.10 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.2</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-sql_2.10 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-sql_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.2</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

and import as follows.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame;
```

Answer (score 0):

> Spark introduced Dataframes in Spark 1.3 release.

Your spark version is **1.2.0**, To access `dataframe API` use spark version >= **1.3.0**

In case you are usind `Datasets` too , use spark version >= **1.6.0**,

> Spark 1.6, introduced datasets API

Answer (score 0):

`DataFrames` provide a domain-specific language for structured data manipulation in `Scala, Java, Python and R`.

As mentioned above, in `Spark 2.0`, "***DataFrames are just Dataset of Rows***" (and that's why you won't find `DataFrame` class in verison 2.0 onwards) in Scala and Java API. These operations are also referred as “untyped transformations” in contrast to “typed transformations” come with strongly typed Scala/Java `Datasets`.

Example:

```
Dataset<Row> ds3 = sqlContext.read().text("XXX/XXX/abc.txt");
```

NOTE: I just added star before "Row" to display angle brackets else was not visible (as a workaround).

For more details, refer Spark documentation, topic - Untyped Dataset Operations (aka DataFrame Operations)

https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.2/sql-programming-guide.html#untyped-dataset-operations-aka-dataframe-operations